# Как очистить память массива структур?

Tags: c, массивы, структуры, struct

```
.
.
.
struct struct1{
    char fam[30],name[30],otch[30],dolj[30],birthday[30],zp[30];
};

struct struct1 sotrudnik[50];
.
.
.
void vvod(void){
if (structsize==0){
    printf("Введите количество сотрудников: ");
    scanf("%d", &structsize);
    if (structsize<1){
        printf("Недопустимое значение\n");
        return;
    }
    for (i=0;i<structsize;i++){
        printf("\nСотрудник #%d\n", i+1);
        printf("Введите фамилию: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(sotrudnik[i].fam);
        printf("Введите имя: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(sotrudnik[i].name);
        printf("Введите отчество: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(sotrudnik[i].otch);
        printf("Введите должность: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(sotrudnik[i].dolj);
        printf("Введите год рождения: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(sotrudnik[i].birthday);
        printf("Введите ЗП: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(sotrudnik[i].zp);
        puts("");
    }
} else {
    printf("Добавить сотрудника?\n1)Да\n2)Нет\n");
    scanf(" %c", &choice);
    switch (choice){
        case '1':
            printf("\nСотрудник #%d\n", structsize+1);
            printf("Введите фамилию: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            gets(sotrudnik[structsize].fam);
            printf("Введите имя: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            gets(sotrudnik[structsize].name);
            printf("Введите отчество: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            gets(sotrudnik[structsize].otch);
            printf("Введите должность: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            gets(sotrudnik[structsize].dolj);
            printf("Введите год рождения: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            gets(sotrudnik[i].birthday);
            printf("Введите ЗП: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            gets(sotrudnik[i].zp);
            structsize++;
            break;
        case '2':
            return;
        default:
            printf("Неверное значение\n");
            break;
    }
}
return;
}
```

Это функция ввода массива сотрудников. Подскажите, как потом очистить

Comment: Что именно очистить? Пройти по всему массиву и записать 0 в первый элемент каждого массива?

Comment: `memset(sotrudnik, 0, sizeof(sotrudnik));` обнулит всю память, занимаемую массивом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам ничего не надо очищать - потому что вы ничего не выделяете динамически. Просто достаточно знать, сколько у вас элементов в массиве занято, и все.

А еще - если ваш компилятор никак не хочет отказаться от функции `gets` - откажитесь от нее сами и никогда, *никогда*, **никогда** ее не используйте...

Comment: Ну на счет gets это не из-за компилятора. Я что-то уже слышал на счет fflush(stdin) и все такое, но scanf не считывает строки с пробелами :c

Comment: Есть fgets и gets_s. Просто gets из стандарта выброшена и к употреблению не рекомендована.